# How to write dynamic variable, request body in terraform

Tags: terraform

I want a code for configuring dynamic variable and request body. i tried this code but it for ansible only but i need terraform

```
- name         : Test var
  hosts        : all
  gather_facts : no
  vars:
    myvariable : false
  tasks:
    - name: param1
      set_fact:
        myvariable: "{{param1}}"
      when: param1 is defined

- name: param2
  set_fact:
    myvariable: "{{ param2 if not myvariable else myvariable + ',' + param2 }}"
  when: param2 is defined

- name: param3
  set_fact:
    myvariable: "{{ param3 if not myvariable else myvariable + ',' + param3 }}"
  when: param3 is defined

- name: default
  set_fact:
    myvariable: "default"
  when: not myvariable

- debug:
   var=myvariable
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Have you looked at Terraform variables and interpolation syntax?